# React component not returning expected value when imported into another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble getting a `boolean` value from a separate component file to display properly in my main `App.js` file.

I created a separate file called `Component.js` where I defined a boolean variable called "test" and exported it. In `App.js`, I imported the variable and logged it to the console. However, the console is showing me the entire `Component` function definition instead of the `boolean` value.

This is my `App.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import test from './Component'

export default function App() {
  console.log(test)
  return (
    <>
   </>
  )
}
```

This is my `Component.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const test = true;

export default function Component() {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have imported the default export
import only test module

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { test } from './Component'

export default function App() {
  console.log(test)
  return (
   <>

   </>
  )
}
```